503 Service Unavailable "maven.tealiumiq.com/java/releases/com/tealium/java/1.3.2/java-1.3.2.jar
503 Service Unavailable "http://maven.tealiumiq.com/java/releases/com/tealium/java/1.3.2/java-1.3.2.jar"
Below, I attempted to download the Tealium java-1.3.2.jar both through the Jenkins CI pipeline and via the terminal. Both methods resulted in the following error, and I have been unable to identify the root cause or a solution. What could be the issue here

Attempting to download using Jenkins CI pipeline:

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not download java-1.3.2.jar (com.tealium:java:1.3.2)
      > Could not get resource 'http://maven.tealiumiq.com/java/releases/com/tealium/java/1.3.2/java-1.3.2.jar'.
         > Connection reset


Attempting to download using the terminal by SSH to Jenkins Agent:

 wget http://maven.tealiumiq.com/java/releases/com/tealium/java/1.3.2/java-1.3.2.jar
--2024-06-18 08:24:20--  http://maven.tealiumiq.com/java/releases/com/tealium/java/1.3.2/java-1.3.2.jar
Resolving maven.tealiumiq.com (maven.tealiumiq.com)... 99.86.229.75, 99.86.229.38, 99.86.229.8, ...
Connecting to maven.tealiumiq.com (maven.tealiumiq.com)|99.86.229.75|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2024-06-18 08:24:20 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.


Check the url via browser... there is a key required for access...

Thorough the web browser, successfully downloaded. No any access key ask.

Error fix through adding the https into to URL as here https://maven.tealiumiq.com/java/releases/com/tealium/java/1.3.2/java-1.3.2.jar
Reference
